# Parse JSON object for unique records

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object

I have following JSON object:

```
var data =JSON.parse('[{"Title":"Test 1","State":"Colorado"}, 
                       {"Title":"Test 1","State":"Arizona"},
                       {"Title":"Test 2","State":"Utah"},
                       {"Title":"Test 2","State":"Arizona"},
                       {"Title":"Test 3","State":"Arizona"}]');
```

How do I parse this `data` object so that I get following output:

```
resultData = [{"Title":"Test 1", State: ["Colorado", "Arizona"]},
              {"Title":"Test 2", State: ["Utah", "Arizona"]},
              {"Title":"Test 3", State: ["Arizona"]}]
```

So far I tried following:

```
var resultData = {},
groupBy = "Title";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!resultData[data[i][groupBy]])
        resultData[data[groupBy]] = [];
    resultData[data[i][groupBy]].push(data[i]);
};
```

but it didn't help and returning some odd object as below:

```
resultData = [{Test 1: [{State: "Colorado"}, {State: "Arizona"}]},
              {Test 2: [{State: "Utah"}, {State: "Arizona"}]},
              {Test 3: [{State: "Arizona"}]}]
```

Can someone help me achieve the same.

Comment: I think this should be array of state `State: ["Colorado", "Arizona"]`

Comment: Thanks for notation! Question updated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what are you trying to achieve is a perfect case for reduce:

## Step 1 - parse data as you already did

```
var data =JSON.parse('[{"Title":"Test 1","State":"Colorado"}, 
                       {"Title":"Test 1","State":"Arizona"},
                       {"Title":"Test 2","State":"Utah"},
                       {"Title":"Test 2","State":"Arizona"},
                       {"Title":"Test 3","State":"Arizona"}]');
```

## Step 2 - combine states with same title into array

```
var titles = data.reduce(function(acc, item){
    var title = item.Title;
    var state = item.State;

    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(acc, title)){
        acc[title] = [];
    }

    acc[title].push(state);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

## Step 3 - build final array using combined states

```
var resultData = Object.keys(titles).map(function(title){
    return {
        Title: title,
        State: titles[title]
    }
});
```

```js
var data = JSON.parse('[{"Title":"Test 1","State":"Colorado"}, {"Title":"Test 1","State":"Arizona"},{"Title":"Test 2","State":"Utah"},{"Title":"Test 2","State":"Arizona"},{"Title":"Test 3","State":"Arizona"}]');

var titles = data.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  var title = item.Title;
  var state = item.State;

  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(acc, title)) {
    acc[title] = [];
  }

  acc[title].push(state);
  return acc;
}, {});

var resultData = Object.keys(titles).map(function(title) {
  return {
    Title: title,
    State: titles[title]
  }
});

console.log(resultData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single loop approach with a closure over a hash table for the same groups.

```js
var data = [{ Title: "Test 1", State: "Colorado" }, { Title: "Test 1", State: "Arizona" }, { Title: "Test 2", State: "Utah" }, { Title: "Test 2", State: "Arizona" }, { Title: "Test 3", State: "Arizona" }],
    key = 'Title',
    grouped = data.reduce(function (group) {
        return function (r, o) {
            if (!group[o[key]]) {
                group[o[key]] = [];
                r.push({ Title: o.Title, State: group[o[key]] });
            }
            group[o[key]].push(o.State);
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```